# Is Github Jobs a good place for a new graduates in software development to look for work?

Tags: job-search

I am wondering if anyone who is a software developer looking for employment finds jobs on [Github Jobs](https://jobs.github.com/).

I will begin my job search soon and was wondering if employers favor applications from Github Jobs more than traditional sources.

Does anyone think Github Jobs is better than Indeed or other job sites?

Comment: that would depend entirely on the individual employer, those looking on github for workers would be interested. Plenty others never heard of github. I only have a vague idea of what github is.

Comment: If you happened to work on some *existing* free software project on github, that is a valuable work experience. If you just show your own code on `github`, it might be less interesting to others. But YMMV

Comment: I was talking about applying to postings on github, not contributing to open source

Comment: I've never found a software engineering job on Github Jobs personally (I didn't even know it existed). I tend to favor LinkedIn, Hired or AngelList. StackOverflow also has its own jobs site (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) too. I really dislike Indeed Prime, because it is very spammy and the employers aren't as good.

Comment: it's more like repos that link to job postings, etc .., but I did not know about github jobs either

Comment: I haven't seen github repos with job postings, but I imagine open source people may do it that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time, systems like this all feed resumes into the same pool. Then, someone filters the applications and sends them to hiring managers/etc.

There are even software tools which employers can use to send a single job to *all*  the various job sites.

By far and away the "best" way to apply is if you know someone. Otherwise, unless the company is very small, most of the job sites will not be overly better compared to others.

Answer (score 2):

So here's a fun story on how IT recruitment works! A typical flow, assuming the recruiter has the job requirement:

1. Go to the major job (dice, monster etc) boards, get all the CVs that were uploaded in the last week. Check to see if any of them match the job keywords
2. Go to linked in, for a small monthly fee you can access everyone on the site - search for people with the skill sets needed
3. do the same as 2. for other niche job boards, like github, stack overflow, etc
4. Screen the cvs pages you get. Look for things like school, company, and other indicators - eg time spent at past jobs, or if they have a github link.

That's it, email those people. Recruiters don't understand code, so they'll just check *that a github link is listed*. As Enderland notes, the github job site will be used by some - but not all - recruiters in this pipeline.

Your best bet is a good up-to-date linkedin profile (throw in your github link there) and to keep updating the various large job boards each week with your cv.

OR, as Enderland notes, just use a contact in the company, because, shockingly, the process I just described is terribly flawed and nobody knows how to fix it.